# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus How to get Message State

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am working on an azure function V2 that peeks the messages from the service bus.
In this function I would like to know the state of the messages (Active, Deferred, Scheduled)

I know that `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage` has a `State` property.

But I am using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`. So How do I get the state of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message`?

**Just an example function that explains my need:**

```cs
[FunctionName("GetStates")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "getstates")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, int>() /** string: state, int: counter **/

    receiver = new MessageReceiver("MyConnectionString", EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath("MyTopic", "MySubscription"));
    var messages = await receiver.PeekBySequenceNumberAsync(receiver.LastPeekedSequenceNumber, 50);

    // How to get the states???

    return new OkObjectResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the `BrokeredMessage` type from track 0 SDK was moved to the `Message` type in track 1 (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus), the `MessageState` was not implemented. While I don't know the rationale behind that decision or wherever this was just missed out by mistake. You could raise an issue with the Azure SDK using the Azure SDK repository issue tracker [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/14205. Thanks for the suggestion